# Google scripts basic authentication

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-authentication

Im trying to log the json data after making an api call however Google always asks for authorisation and I need it to automatically authenticate using the api key provided .

Putting the url into the browser directly , I only need to supply the api key as the username .

The code im using is as follows :

```
function testapi(){
  var encode =  Utilities.base64Encode('apikey', Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
  Logger.log(encode);
  var option = {
    headers : {
      Authorization: "Basic "+ encode
    }   
  }
  var url = "https://apiurl.json";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option).getContentText()
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: I think that in your script, the error occurs at the first line of ``options.headers``. And even if the object of ``options`` is existing, it is not used in your script. But in your question, those are not mentioned. So if your script is not the latest one, can you update it? And, although I'm not sure about the specification of API you use, the method of API you want to use should be called by GET method?

Comment: Hi Tanaike , I've edited the code .

Comment: This is your latest script. If it's correct, the basic authorization is not correct for this script. I think that ``"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)`` you removed can be used for the basic authorization. Although I'm not sure about the specification of API you use, the method of API you want to use should be called by GET method? And can you provide the specification of the API?

Comment: Yes this is the latest script , the specification of API I'm using is : http://deskdeveloper.teamwork.com/desk/#!/tags/Get_Desk_Tags